# imagen webp no se visualiza en iphone

Tags: html5, iphone

lo que pasa es que cambie todas mis imágenes jpg a webp, alguien de casualidad me puede decir porque no se visualiza en  en iphone, e investigado  y dice que después de la versión ios 10 sirve y tengo un iphone x y no se visualiza

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

gracias,quedo atento.

Answer (score 1):

Asegúrate primero de que tu iPhone puede ver los webp

https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_500,h_333,f_auto,c_fill/dog2.webp

Y la verdad no creo que Safari soporte webp

https://caniuse.com/#feat=webp

Si te preocupa el peso de la imagenes (jpg, png), minifícalas:

https://imagecompressor.com/es/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]